# How to unsubscribe Observer?

Tags: angular, angular7, angular8

There is observer:

```
export class ListenerService {

    private action: Subject<IActionData> = new Subject();

    apply(data?: IActionData) {
        this.action.next(data);
    }

    changes(): Observable<any> {
        return this.action.asObservable();
    }
}
```

**Using is:**

```
this.sub = this.listener.changes();
this.sub.subscribe((res: IActionData) => {});
```

In destroy component I tried to unset `this.sub`:

```
 ngOnDestroy() {
    if (this.sub) {
      console.log(this.sub);
      this.sub.unsubsribe();
    }
  }
```

It says:

> ERROR TypeError: this.sub.unsubsribe is not a function
>       at VersionsAddressComponent.ngOnDestroy

Comment: Did you misspell `unsubscribe` as `unsubsribe`? :D

Comment: maybe its a misspell cause you can see that the error given is also ```unsubsribe ``` xD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

subscription value in a component like

```
sub: Subscription;
```

And your subscribe will be

```
this.sub = this.listner.changes.subscribe((res: IActionData) => {});
```

And onDestroy Will be

```
ngOnDestroy() {
   this.sub.unsubsribe();
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

That should do the job:

```
this.sub = this.listener.changes().subscribe((res: IActionData) => {});
this.sub.unsubsribe();
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use RXJS Subscription:

```
  subscription = new Subscription() ; 
this.subscription.add(this.listener.changes().subscribe((res: IActionData) => {}));



  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

`Observable` cannot be unsubscribed, `subscription` can be unsubscribed:

For Ex:

```js
this.sub = this.listener.changes().subscribe((res: IActionData) => {});
```

And then you can unsubscribe it, the way you have done:

```js
ngOnDestroy() {
   this.sub.unsubsribe();
}
```

Comment: I still get: `WordDictComponent.html:4 ERROR TypeError: this.sub.unsubsribe is not a function`

Comment: Can you post your code in stackblitz and share the link to have more insight